# How to get dimensions of document in WebView?

Tags: webview, javafx

I need to get snapshot of whole html document inside webview, I do it in such manner:

```
BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
browser = new WebView();
webEngine = browser.getEngine();
webEngine.loadContent(_content);
pane.setCenter(browser);
Scene scene = new Scene(pane);

try {                   
    SnapshotParameters params = new SnapshotParameters();
    Image image = pane.snapshot(params, null);
    File out = new File("c:\\1.png");
    ImageIO.write( SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null)  , "png", out);        
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Problem is that I doesn't know height and width of document.

Answer (score 0):

Following code gives the width & height. It runs the javascript to get the values.

```
int height = Integer.parseInt(webEngine.executeScript("var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement; Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );").toString());
int width = Integer.parseInt(webEngine.executeScript("var body = document.body, html = document.documentElement; Math.max( body.scrollWidth, body.offsetWidth, html.clientWidth, html.scrollWidth, html.offsetWidth );").toString());
```